# How to input embeddings directly to a huggingface model instead of tokens?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm going over the [huggingface tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter2/6?fw=pt) where they showed how tokens can be fed into a model to generate hidden representations:

```
import torch
from transformers import RobertaTokenizer
from transformers import RobertaModel

checkpoint = 'roberta-base'
tokenizer = RobertaTokenizer.from_pretrained(checkpoint)
model = RobertaModel.from_pretrained(checkpoint)

sequences = ["I've been waiting for a HuggingFace course my whole life."]

tokens = tokenizer(sequences, padding=True)
out = model(torch.tensor(tokens['input_ids']))
out.last_hidden_state
```

But how can I input word embeddings directly instead of tokens? That is, I have another model that generates word embeddings and I need to feed those into the model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most (every?) huggingface encoder model supports that with the parameter [inputs_embeds](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.19.2/en/model_doc/roberta#transformers.RobertaModel.forward.inputs_embeds):

```py
import torch
from transformers import RobertaModel

m = RobertaModel.from_pretrained("roberta-base")

my_input = torch.rand(2,5,768)

outputs = m(inputs_embeds=my_input)
```

P.S.: Don't forget the attention mask in case this is required.

Comment: Wow this is awesome, thanks! Can you explain the part about the attention mask and the required dimensions?

Comment: @Penguin: Please check this [explanation](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/glossary#attention-mask).